# Adding a new option in FireFox and IE save dialog

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, plugins

I want to disable the custom Save Dialog of IE and Firefox OR add a new "Save to My Location" option in it.
I think I need to create plug-ins for IE and Firefox.

Comment: You wouldn't have an actual question to go along with your statement there, would you? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think you must write Extensions for the browsers, too. I don't know how that would be done for IE for Firefox you could start there:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($.browser.msie)
{
    selectElement.add(option);
}
else
{
    selectElement.add(option, null);
}
```